# Command to be in .bat file - Replace directory contain specific word

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a folder with the name "mahmood_20200401" and it is in location "d:\mahmood_20200401". I need a command to rename the folder but I don't want to mention the full name as the date keeps changing.

**Needs:**

I need a command to rename the folder without mentioning the full name of the folder. I found a lot of examples where they mention how to rename a file if its contain specific word or letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly use `Rename-Item` because its -Path and obsiously -LiteralPath arguments does not accept wildcard as stated in official doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item#parameters

However `GCI` does accept wildcard, so you can use GCI to get the file and pipe it to Rename-Item :

```
gci mahmood_20* | Rename-Item -NewName mahmood_without_date_or_whatever
```

Comment: nice Answer! you could make it somewhat nicer by expanding the GCI alias, using the parameter name in that call instead of just the bare value, adding `-Directory` to get only dirs, and - finally [*grin*] - wrapping the code after the pipe to avoid needlessly long lines of code.

Comment: it works perfect in Powershall.. Is it possible to have it within cmd  ?

Comment: That may depend @MahmoodAbdullah upon whether you're intending to unmark this answer as your accepted solution. Not many people will be willing to give their time in formaulating a solution for you, when you've already accepted a different answer. Besides that, your question is lacking sufficient detail for a robust answer to be provided. Are you looking for any directory with a name beginning with `mahmood_` in the root of the `D:` drive? and is there only going to be one such directory? or is the date important too? Also how are you wanting to rename it? which part? and to what?